# Setting up ASP.NET SQLServer session state in SQL server using a script

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session-state

Using the ASPNET_REGSQL tool I generate a script using the following:

```
ASPNET_REGSQL.exe -ssadd -sstype c -sqlexportonly c:\addseesion.sql -E -d myDatabase -s myServer
```

In the script that is created there is this comment:

```
--------------------------------------------------
Note:                                             
Do not run this file manually.                    
You should use aspnet_regsql.exe to install       
and uninstall SQL session state.                  
--------------------------------------------------
```

The trouble is, in the environment that I work I must develop a script to give to the DBA's, they don't have the .NET sdk and wont be able to use the aspnet_regsql tool.

Can this script be run as is?

Comment: you mean .NET Framework or .NET SDK?

Comment: I meant SDK but I now see that it is part of the framework, so perhaps I will have the DBA just use the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aspnet_regsql tool is actually part of .NET Framework. you can find this tool at 
`%WindDiR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<framework version>`

Comment: Well, my DBA tried to run the script but I had difficulty getting my app to run.  He decided to just try using the command and everything works now.  What is the purpose of generating the script if it can't be used for anything??